# Test timing out when 2 expect statements present

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, coffeescript

I have this in my CoffeeScript test:

```
# List 1st bucket to find 1 object
.then -> 
  s3.listObjectsV2(
    Bucket: bucketName
  ).promise()

.then (data) ->
  expect(data.Contents.length).to.deep.equal(1)

# List 2nd bucket to find an empty list of objects
.then -> 
  s3.listObjectsV2(
    Bucket: bucketName2
  ).promise()

.then (data) ->
  expect(data.Contents.length).to.deep.equal(0)
```

This errors with `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.`.

If I remove one of:

```
  .then (data) ->
    expect(data.Contents.length).to.deep.equal(1)
```

or:

```
  .then (data) ->
    expect(data.Contents.length).to.deep.equal(0)
```

The test passes. I have a feeling it's related to a promise not returning bir what is wrong that causes the test to fail when both `expect` statements are present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding:

```
this.timeout(5000);
```

The test now passes